# Можно ли отразить tile по оси x

Tags: c#, unity3d, tile

Я заполняю TileMap через скрипт вот так:

```
private void DrawSpriteOnTileMap(int x, int y, bool flipX, Tilemap tm, Sprite sp){
    Tile tile = new Tile();
    tile.sprite = sp;
    if(flipX){
        ...
    }
    tm.SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, -y, 0), tile);
}
```

Спрайты я получаю так: `var sp = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Prefabs/Tiles");`

Каким образом можно отразить tile по оси x?
В интернете ничего полезного найти не смог, неужели придется создавать для каждого спрайта его перевернутую копию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как я решил проблему:

```
private void DrawSpriteOnTileMap(int x, int y, bool flipX, Tilemap tm, Sprite sp){

    Tile tile = new Tile();
    tile.sprite = sp;
    tm.SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, -y, 0), tile);

    if(flipX)
        Walls.SetTransformMatrix(new Vector3Int(x, -y, 0), Matrix4x4.TRS( Vector3Int.zero,
                                                                          Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0),
                                                                          new Vector3(-1, 1, 1)));
}
```

оставлю тут, вдруг кому-нибудь поможет

Comment: Примите свой ответ :)

Comment: точно, спасибо. Просто принять свой ответ можно только через сутки, вот я и забыл